# Overflow Hidden exceptions to the rule?

Tags: css, overflow

I need to show an element (image) overlaying a `Div` that has a `overflow:hidden` applied to it. Since the overflow is hidden , its naturally covering anything I want to sit on top of it. How do I get around this?

Comment: Maybe if you post some html and css or maybe even demo page we can help you. This way its really hard to say anything.

Comment: Well, if you can use Javascript, you could actually change the structure of the page to get around the problem, by moving the entire element out of the `overflow: hidden` container.

Comment: Please post sample code to convey the question clearly. Here's something to start with on jsfiddle.net - http://www.jsfiddle.net/uamSr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you can remove the overflow hidden. Do you need it to clear floats? If so you can substitute with a clearfix.

Would be better if you provided more info.

Comment: No, I cant remove the 'Overflow: Hidden' property. It's critical to the thing I'm designing. Its not a traditional website. I need to somehow move something forcibly into an area covered by that div.

Comment: You could try `position:relative` with a negative margin. I forget if that gets clipped, though. Or you could somehow create a parent div and put the new overlay as a child, and make your current overflow hidden a sibling of the overlay.

Comment: Not sure how exactly but thank you, `position:relative` with a negative margin fixed the problem. We must be somehow speaking the same language. :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your Div with overflow:hidden(d1) on another div(d2) with no overflow value, add another floating div over the wrapper (d2) and put your image or other elements inside it :)
This will work given your general description. If you put a sample of your HTML/CSS code it'll be easier to fix for your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the overflow hidden is the problem?
It sounds more like a layering issue if the div is covering the image you're trying to display.